# Error using Restful with JBOSS runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, maven, jboss

I have created a maven webapp and i'm trying to use the restful services and a JBoss 7.0 runtime. 
I've changed the `web.xml` to call the restful services using `javax.ws.rs` from which i have also added the jar to the buildpath. The server starts perfectly, so there is no errors or failures in related to the `web.xml` file and i can successfully call the first page. 
I've wrote a class called `RestService` wich is supposed to do something when i call another url (to be precise `localhost:8080/myPrj/rest/hello/first`), but when i call the url it shows an error on my eclipse console and on the webbrowser.
What am i doing wrong ?
Please help a newbie

this is my web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is the class Restsservice

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;
import url_checker.*;


@Path("/hello")
public class RestService {


        @GET
        @Path("first")
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        public String hello(){
            System.out.println("here");
            return "Hi everyone";
        }
        @GET
        @Path("go")
        public String go(){
            runProgramMethod();
            return "<p1>Programm running</p1>";
        }
        private void runProgramMethod() {
            MainPauserMethod runner = new MainPauserMethod();


    }
}
```

This is the errormessage on the browser:

> type Status report
>
> message Bad arguments passed to public
>   RestService$ServerService(RestService) (
>   org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException: Could not find message
>   body reader for type: class RestService of content type: */*
>
> description The server encountered an internal error (Bad arguments
>   passed to public RestService$ServerService(RestService) (
>   org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException: Could not find message
>   body reader for type: class RestService of content type: */*) that
>   prevented it from fulfilling this request.

And this one on the console on eclipse:

```
16:09:37,134 SCHWERWIEGEND [org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Failed executing GET hello/first: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.InternalServerErrorException: Bad arguments passed to public RestService$ServerService(RestService)  ( org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException: Could not find message body reader for type: class RestService of content type: */*
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:122) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.resourcefactory.POJOResourceFactory.createResource(POJOResourceFactory.java:43) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:496) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:139) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.NamingValve.invoke(NamingValve.java:57) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:154) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:667) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:952) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_65]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_65]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:82) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the implementation of JAX-RS is RestEasy you need to use a web.xml like:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: i need 15 reputation no? and i have only 9